# LightopenID regarding protecting web pages

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

So I have the example-google.php script working, after loging in it throws the default user string has logged in. But my question is how does this protect anything?

Lets say I have //127.0.0.1/example-google.php and I added a href to //127.0.0.1/abc.php after the login is successful.

Well what keeps someone from just typing 127.0.0.1/abc.php? granted I could use $_SESSION to verify that "someone" logged in. But is that going to be enough? Is there a way to re-verify that the user that is trying to access abc.php is truely logged in when thrown from the other page?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the idea is that you use the session store, indeed.

For example, in my site I have a OpenID login using Steam Community. When a user logs in, after the mode / validate checks etc. from the LightOpenID example, I save their unique identifier in the session store (in this case a SteamID, in your case an email address presumably), then can just use this freely for subsequent requests.

As the session store is server-side, a user cannot impersonate another one without gaining their session cookie (session hijacking is another topic that someone else can go into much more detail on, but I'll give it a shot if requested), but most attacks will be defeated by also storing and validating the requesting IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a couple of mysql tables (one for sessions and one for user information) and store session information in the session table and include a reference to the users table.  When a user successfully logs in with their OID provider they are sent back to my site with the confirmation from the provider.  I keep track of my user from then on via their session id.

I wipe the session if they choose to log out, but maintain the user info for comments/posts on the site to track who said what.

I actually put a link to "?login={service}" which sends the request to the OID provider and redirects back to that page and on return from the provider it takes the successful login and stores the appropriate information and redirects the user back to the original page where they clicked the "login" button for whichever {service}.  You only display the "members only" content if they are verified via OID.  You don't create a standard HTML page at abc.php without any sort of way to confirm ID and I think the header redirect is important because it cleans up the URL displayed in the address.